# Error When Running Author.save() in MongoAlchemy

Tags: python, mongodb-atlas, flask-mongoengine, mongoalchemy

It now seems that I can connect to the MongoDB Cluster, but when I try to save then I get the error below:

TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'safe'

I have Flask-MongoAlchemy 0.7.1 installed because 0.7.2 doesn't connect at all.

I am following the simple example on the documentation page. In models.py I have the following:

```
class Author(db.Document):
    name = db.StringField()
```

I run the following

```
from myapp import db
from myapp.models import Author
author = Author(name="James")
author.save()
```

Then I get the error.

I have seen a post on this and have tried adding the required=True to where I declare name. I can confirm the pymongo version is 3.8.0.

I have found that pymongo needs to be 3.8.0 to be able to use the URI with "mongodb+srv", but it needs to be 2.8.0 to enable the safe argument to be passed. The problem is that my code is in python3 and Atlas tells me the connection string has to have "mongodb+srv" so this conflicts with the versions of pymongo. I am not sure if it is even possible to get this working using Flask-MongoAlchemy.

Comment: Can you add the error you get?

Comment: Hi Pablo, the error is "TypeError: init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'safe'" when trying to save the instance of Author. I checked the documentation and it looks like the version of pymongo doesn't take the safe argument anymore, but the version of Flask-MongoAlchemy is passing that argument still.

Answer (score 1):

#### **TLDR:** Migrate to MongoEngine. It is painless

Came here looking for answers. couldn't find anything online. on GitHub MongoAlchemy says, it is no longer being maintained. If you are looking for answers like me, I had to migrate to [MongoEngine](http://docs.mongoengine.org/projects/flask-mongoengine/en/latest/)

Comment: Sorry, this is so long ago that I have no idea if there was a resolution for it or what it was.